# How to rewrite same file

Tags: php, file-io

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
$f = fopen('test', 'w');
fwrite($f, 'Hi');
fclose($f);
```

But I have a loop that does some expensive stuff (with files), and I'd like to avoid opening and closing the file handle every time I want to overwrite "test"

It should be something like this:

```
$f = fopen('test', 'w');

$i = 0;
while($ < 50000){

  $i++;
  foverwrite($f, 'i = ' . $i);

  sleep(5); // just a example

}

fclose($f);
```

Is this possible?

This script runs in the background in CLI mode and I'm reading the test file from the web with ajax like every 2 seconds. Basically I'm trying to display a progress bar lol

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve ?
AKA, what would be the output of your file before and after?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just prepare a string inside that loop, and then write it to a file???

Comment: But that's what I`m doing, $i is the string :)  zonzon: it would be just a line: i = number (number changes in the loop)

Comment: I still don't get exactly what you want, you want to overwrite over the entire file ?
If you want to display a progress bar, you should just write a single line with the % of current progress.

Comment: yes exactly, that's what I want, but if possible without opening and closing the file every time I do that

Comment: As it stands, I feel like you should open two files, one to write just a single int, representing the percentage.
And the other one to do whatever you do.

If you ultimately need to access the line corresponding to the percentage.
Just write the current $i and the percentage value.

Comment: i didn't get what u r looking for ? why are u ovrwrtng the file ? you are not reading data?then why are u saving data at each time ? oly last is needed ? wht's requirement for saving it ? let it be clearer otherwise this  bounty  will be a waste .... wht's ur real rquirmnt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go along with your example, you could implement your `foverwrite()` function using [`frewind()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php) like this:

```
function foverwrite($handle,$content)
  {
  frewind($handle);
  return fwrite($handle,$content);
  }
```

This function will return `fwrite()`'s return value, so it can readily replace `fwrite()` where needed. Also, in case of opening the file in append mode (a or a+) it will just append contens, as `frewind()` will make no difference.

However, concerning the purpose of your script, which clearly is *[interprocess communication](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20interprocess%20communication)*, you should take a look at more efficient techniques, like [shared memory](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php).

Answer (score 9):

You can update the content of a file by rewinding the file pointer, see [fseek()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php). Be careful, once you set file lenght to N by writing N bytes to it, next time, if you rewind and write X < N bytes, the file will remain N bytes long, containing X bytes of new data and N-X bytes of old stuff.

Anyway, don't worry about opening and closing files several times, they will be cached. Or you can open it on a ramdisk partition.

Answer (score 8):

You can keep the file and just rewrite over the contents, while then truncating the file if the size changed. This will be faster than overwriting or deleting and rewriting.

```
$f = fopen('test', 'w');
$i = 0;
while($i < 50000){
  $i++;

  rewind($f);
  $data = 'i = ' . $i;
  fwrite($f, $data);
  ftruncate($f, strlen($data)); // <---------- Here's the ticket

  sleep(5);
}

fclose($f);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in following ways

```
$data = [];//initiate the $data variable as empty array
$i = 0;
while($i < 50000){

  $data[] = 'i = ' . $i;
  $i++;
}
file_put_contents('file.txt', implode("\n", $data));// implode the array
```

Comment: Did you mean `$i < 50000` as the condition? (Currently you just have `$` for the variable).

Answer (score 1):

If you're just aiming to keep a file updated so that it can be accessed by AJAX requests, then do you *really* need to update it 50000 times? A simple way of cutting your overhead would be to update the file less often. Like this, for example:

```
for ($i=0; $i<50000; $i++) {

  // update progress file every 1000 iterations:
  if (!($i % 1000)) file_put_contents('./file.txt', "i = $i");

  // --- do stuff ---

}
file_put_contents($f, "i = 50000");
```